# inverse function theorem on manifolds

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

suppose there are two 3-manifolds(consider them as orthogonal matrices $SL(2,\mathbb R)$), and there is $F:SL(2,\mathbb R)\to SL(2,\mathbb R)$, given by $F(A）=A^3$. Can we apply inverse function theorem on these two manifolds so we can say that there are two open sets $U,V$, for each $B\in V \subset SL(2,\mathbb R)$), there is $A\in U\subset SL(2,\mathbb R)$, such that $A^3=B$. Usually we can only use inverse function theorem on two open sets of $\mathbb R^k$, is there a generalized version on manifolds? If it exists, how can we justify it?

Comment: If you have two manifolds with same dimension $k$ and a map between then, taking charts will give you a map $\mathbb{R}^{k}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k}$ and you can use the inverse function theorem you already know to wirite a version of it for manifolds.

Comment: Warning: $SL(2,\Bbb R)$ is the set of $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant $1$. The set of orthogonal matrices is denoted $O(2,\Bbb R)$. But, yes, the inverse function theorem applies to maps between manifolds of the same dimension because you can always use charts to reduce to the Euclidean case, as @Studzinski said.